# Update of Date column in oracle sql is not behaving properly

Tags: oracle, date

```
update template
set activedate=(SELECT unique activedate
                from template
                where status = 'Draft'
                      and activedate like '%01-JAN-99%')   
where status = 'Draft'
      and activedate not like '%01-JAN-99%;
```

when I use above statement, Dates get updated to 01-JAN-2099 as updated by JDBC front end.
but, when I use below query instead of that

```
update template
set activedate = '01JAN-99'
where status = 'Draft'
      and activedate not like '%01-JAN-99%;
```

Could anybody explains why does this happens?

Comment: What is the datatype of the activedate column?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: `LIKE` is for string values, **not** for dates

Comment: Your question is incomplete. *What* is the difference between the two results that has you confused? BTW: You *do* know that `SELECT unique activedate` doesn't give you one record with one activedate, but one record *per* activedate, yes?

Answer (score 1):

when you operate with dates this way you need convert them to varchar

```
to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

and your query should be smth like this:

```
update template
set activedate = to_date('01-JAN-99', 'DD-MON-YY')
where status = 'Draft'
      and to_char(activedate, 'DD-MON-YY') not like '%01-JAN-99%;
```

or better (as it was suggested use numbers):

```
update template
set activedate = to_date('01-01-1999', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
where status = 'Draft'
      and activedate != to_date('01-01-1999', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

see more info

[to_char(datetime)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)

[to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: Note that `to_date('01-JAN-99', 'DD-MON-YY')` might break on non-english computeres (e.g. it will fail if the client computer is using a french locale). It is better to use _numbers_ for months, not names. Also `99` for the year is a potential problem as well (is it 1999 or 2099?) You should **always** use 4 digit years: `to_char('01-01-2099', 'dd-mm-yyyy')`